# Laravel table refuse to be registered on migrations table and rollbacked or migrated

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a migration table refuse to be registered in migrations tables ..

```
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table    1
2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table  1
2016_03_21_010421_create_orders_table   1
2016_03_21_010549_create_types_table    1
2016_03_21_010722_create_materials_table    1
2016_03_21_010814_create_ratings_table  1
2016_03_21_011205_create_costs_table    1
2016_03_21_012114_create_locations_table    1
2016_06_02_181122_create_assignments_table  1
2016_06_25_001455_create_bills_table    1
2016_07_26_195012_create_roles_table    1
2016_08_06_205440_create_permissions_table  1
2016_08_11_013917_create_material_order_table   1
```

file : 2017_03_04_201351_create_permission_role_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreatePermissionRoleTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->foreign('permission_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('permissions')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('permission_role');
    }
}
```

this is the migration ..

i tried `composer dump` also it does not appear ..

it refuse to migrate ..

i deleted manually but have the same error upon `migrate:refresh` or `migrate` after `rollback`.

Finally that is  the error :

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'permission_role' already exists (SQL: create table `permission_role` (`permission_id` in
  t unsigned not null, `role_id` int unsigned not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'permission_role' already exists
```

table info :  `innoDB` .

github repo : link

https://github.com/lifesound/fixgate

Comment: it's `composer dump-autoload` not `composer-dump`

Comment: it works the same

Comment: first time to know that, you could try to delete all your tables manually and try again.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Ver 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing the `id column` in the permission table to (increments) instead of  (enum) .. Although it was what i did not want ,
so i have to add the enum to other column ..

In these cases as i learned from that error .. with 2 days lost testing :

1. Be sure of your tables order . relational table should come after
   parent tables .
2. composer dump when changing any file name , delete or add .
3. The relational columns should be  unsigned and index .
4. Use migrate:reset to delete all your migrations . then migrate again.
5. If you changed the database config , don't forget to clear config .
6. Be sure that your table is innoDB .

Answer (score 0):

You already have the table permission_role, now your migrations table is not aligned with your database.

If you know what to do you can edit manually the migrations table, restore the file you discarded and run "composer dump-autoload" followed by a migrate

Probably the best way is to drop manually all the tables (including migrations table) and rerun migrate. If you can drop all your tables.

Comment: I did all of that

Comment: and the message is always the same?

Comment: drop the database and recreate it

Comment: I did .. and also , i create new db

Comment: Have you tried clearing your application cache, deleting the database, recreating the database, and then running your migrations, in that order?